# Parse TCP JSON Stream and emit each object via Socket.io

Tags: json, node.js, sockets, tcp, socket.io

I am working with a data feed that sends a JSON stream over a TCP socket and I'm using node.js/socket.io to emit the stream to a browser client.

Everything is working except I need each JSON object to emitted as a separate message from the socket.io server. In the client the messages are received like this:

```
//Message 1:
{"type":"TYPE_1","odds":[{"eventId":"foo","odds":[{"oddId":foo,"oddType":"LIVE","source":"foo"}]}]}
//Message 2:
{"type":"TYPE_2","odds":[{"eventId":"foo","odds":[{"oddId":foo,"oddType":"LIVE","source":"foo"}]}]}
{"type":"TYPE_3","odds":[{"eventId":"foo","odds":[{"oddId":foo,"oddType":"LIVE","source":"foo"}]}]}
//Message 3:
{"type":"TYPE_4","odds":[{"eventId":"foo","od
//Message 4:
ds":[{"oddId":foo,"oddType":"LIVE","source":"foo"}]}]}
```

The data feed docs state: "All messages sending to your application will form a JSON stream (no delimiter between messages), so you may need a decoder that support JSON stream."

So the stream is strictly correct but I need each object as separate message.

I have looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream and others but am very new to nodejs and socketio and am not sure how to implement them in to the server.

Have also read [How can I parse the first JSON object on a stream in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829811/how-can-i-parse-the-first-json-object-on-a-stream-in-js), [nodejs JSON.parse(data_from_TCP_socket)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158219/nodejs-json-parsedata-from-tcp-socket), http://www.sebastianseilund.com/json-socket-sending-json-over-tcp-in-node.js-using-sockets.

I think it's something to do with buffer chunk lengths and them being too big so the messages get split but that could be wrong! I'm guessing I need a delimiter check that balances brackets but not sure how to go about it or if the right approach.

**My Server Script:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var net = require('net');
var port = 8992;              // Datafeed port
var host = '127.0.0.1';      // Datafeed IP address

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('A user connected to me the server');

  //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('A user disconnected');
  });
});

//Create a TCP socket to read data from datafeed
var socket = net.createConnection(port, host);

socket.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log("Error Connecting");
});

socket.on('connect', function(connect) {
  console.log('connection established');
  socket.write('{"type":"SUBSCRIBE"}');
});

socket.on('data', function(data) {
  //console.log('DATA ' + socket.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
  var data = data.toString();
  io.sockets.emit('event', JSON.stringify(data));
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**My Client:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Hello world</title></head>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  </script>
  <body>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <script>
      socket.on('event', function(data){
        var t = JSON.parse(data.toString('utf8'));
        $('#messages').prepend($('<li>').text(t));
        console.log('Got event from Server:', t);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help or guidance would be amazing as really struggling with this.

Answer (score 4):

A common delimiter to use is a newline character (`\n`). If you have that appended to your JSON messages it will be very easy to parse the messages. For example:

```
var sockBuf = '';
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  sockBuf += data;
  var i;
  var l = 0;
  while ((i = sockBuf.indexOf('\n', l)) !== -1) {
    io.sockets.emit('event', sockBuf.slice(l, i));
    l = i + 1;
  }
  if (l)
    sockBuf = sockBuf.slice(l);
});
```

or a more efficient, but slightly less simple solution:

```
var sockBuf = '';
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  var i = data.indexOf('\n');
  if (i === -1) {
    sockBuf += data;
    return;
  }
  io.sockets.emit('event', sockBuf + data.slice(0, i));
  var l = i + 1;
  while ((i = data.indexOf('\n', l)) !== -1) {
    io.sockets.emit('event', data.slice(l, i));
    l = i + 1;
  }
  sockBuf = data.slice(l);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this but have just tested both versions and nothing is emitted from the server now. Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Your TCP server needs to be writing the JSON messages with newlines after them, are you sure it's now doing that?

Comment: Yes have just output the raw data from the data feed to console and it shows each json node starts on newline

Comment: I changed the delimeter in your code examples to '}{' just to check and the server emits but with the same problem as my question

Comment: I don't know then, the code I suggested works for me locally with a simple TCP server that writes newline-delimited JSON strings to connected sockets.

Comment: What are you using for your simple TCP server?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3f54a87f5363663837990a3c6448b992)'s a gist of what I used to test.

Comment: Ok so data feed wasn't newline delimited, is now as I'm adding it in before your code and server is emitting correctly. Really close now except I'm getting json parse errors client side. Do I need to add a similar delimiter check in the client before attempting to parse?

Comment: No, the frontend client should not need to, since a newline should indicate a complete JSON message. Are you sure that the TCP server isn't accidentally formatting its JSON output (with additional newlines) or similar? If it isn't, what is the parse error on the frontend?

Comment: So the error in client (browser) is: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 4637 of the JSON data. Theres more but at different column numbers. Does the slice not remove the newline? io.sockets.emit('event', sockBuf.slice(l, i));

Comment: If change this line to: io.sockets.emit('event', JSON.stringify(sockBuf.slice(l, i))); then the errors stop but the json parse doesn't seem to convert to an object. I can view the output by: $('#messages').prepend($('<li>').text(t)); but $('#messages').prepend($('<li>').text(t.type)); doesn't output anything.

Comment: I have added an updated server script to the question so you can see how I'm adding the newline delimiter. really appreiciate your help with this

Comment: I would suggest using the second code example I posted instead of the first. Also, remove the `data.replace()` you added. Then instead of calling `io.sockets.emit('event', ...)`, use `console.dir(...)` so you can see exactly what is being sent to the frontend. That should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Finally got this working, thank you @mscdex ! the data.replace() needed a global flag as it was missing some of the json nodes resulting in multiple nodes still being combined. that was causing the parse fail and errors in client

Comment: New to SO. How's best to mark this as answered? Add the final anwser myself?